# Number input with button inside

Tags: html, css

I know I can set a submit button inside an input but I try to build it my self.

The desired result is :

[image]

So the pink box is this div :

```
<div class="numberSubmittion SimpleInputBox buttonCorners brandBlue" >
    <input type="number" class="font"  name="productPrice" placeholder="Enter Your Phone Number">
    <button type="submit" value=">">
</div>
```

**css**:

```
.numberSubmittion {
    height: 100%;
}

.numberSubmittion input {
  height: 100%;
  width:75%;
  margin-left: 0px;
  font-size: 14;
  border:0px solid clear;
  outline-width: 0;
  border-width: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
}


.numberSubmittion button {
  height: 100%;
  width:25%;
  display: inline-block;
  outline-width: 0;
  border-width: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.1);
}
```

So I get the input right, how I locate the button to the right ?
Right now the button is outside the pink div and is on the left.

**EDIT**

After fixing my html to remove spaces its :

```
<input type="number" class="font"  name="productPrice" placeholder="Enter Your Phone Number"><button type="submit" value="ab">
```

but now when they are aligned, the input div has some top margin and is not vertically aligned with the pink one, while the button aligned well.

Comment: So you want the ">" to be inside the pink `.numberSubmittion` element?

Comment: Please fix your formatting errors and include the rest of the `CSS`.

Comment: @AndrewL64 yes. Please see my edit of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

1. you can't have spaces in `html` :

   ```
      <input type="number" class="font"  name="productPrice" placeholder="Enter Your Phone Number"><button type="submit" value="ab">
   ```
2. Then when using `inline-block` you must align to top both elements `vertical-align:top`

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html {
    font-size: 62.25%;
}

body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.num-box {
    margin: 5rem auto;
    width: 300px;
    display: flex;
    background-color: pink;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.num-input {
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    padding: 2rem;
    border: 0;
    background: transparent;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 2rem;
    outline: none;
}

.num-btn {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
}

.num-btn::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    content: '✔';
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #9e9b9b;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World From Gaurav</title>
     
</head>
<body>
    <div class="num-box">
        <input type="number" name="" id="" class="num-input" placeholder="Type number">
        <button class="num-btn"></button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```